# Storing custom application configurations on cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

Is there a way to store custom application configurations on the Cumulocity backend through the c8y.sdk? I would like to store a JSON with configuration information specific to an application created using the the smart app toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

You can save settings at the tenant by using [`c8ySettings`](http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/core/c8y.core.service:c8ySettings),
**BUT** you have a limitation of 256 characters per value.

I'm struggling with the same problem of storing larger plugin configurations without any success.

Answer (score 1):

I asked about this from cumulocity support and they said it is possible to store custom JSON under managedobjects because at the moment they dont support storing JSON to database otherwise.

So you will need "create" or "admin" rights to inventory to be able to create new managedobject. You can store values like this:

```
    var userSettings = {
     type: 'userDashboardSettings',
     yourSetting: somesetting,
     id: settingsId
    };
    c8yInventory.save(userSettings).then(function(){
      //do something
    });
```

then you can search this newly created managedobject like this:

```
c8yInventory.list({
      type: 'userDashboardSettings',
      owner: id,
      pageSize: 2
    }).then(function (settings) { //do something }
```

So this way I was for example able to save user specific settings.

To find user dashboard settings do GET to: https://yourdomain.com/inventory/managedObjects/?type=userDashboardSettings&owner=IDHERE

To Delete managedObject do DELETE to: https://yourdomain.com/inventory/managedObjects/IDHERE

To see all managedObjects do GET: https://yourdomain.com/inventory/managedObjects

Type and user are important, this is how you find the managedobject.